# iPhone won't boot after installing higher capacity battery

Tags: iphone, battery

I wanted to upgrade my iPhone 5 to a higher capacity 2680mAh battery, but when I installed it the Apple flashes on and off and the phone will not turn on. I had to reinstall the old battery. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You should only use the battery that's for your phone. The phone is not meant to take a higher wattage battery, so it will malfunction.

To put that into context, it's like trying to put a V8 engine into a hairdryer. It won't work.